# Why is Maple norm giving the wrong answer?

Tags: maple

Hello I'm trying to use Maple to calculate the norm of different vectors,
as an easy example lets take the vector $h = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\
4\\
\end{array}
\right)$ where the length is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$, but every command in maple I try is telling me the result is 4. Both $VectorNorm(h)$ and $Norm(h)$

Am I wrong, or why is maple nearly **always** giving the wrong result?

Comment: Maple is calculating the $\infty$ norm.  Please read the documentation for more details and how to calculate the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1):

Try $Norm(h,2)$. The command $Norm(h)$ computes the infinity norm of $h$, which is indeed 4 for your vector.